# LeJOS: How write integer data succesfully to a file in NXT

Tags: java, dataoutputstream, nxt, lejos-nxj

I am working on some AI project which I am supposed to implement a controller using fuzzy logic on my NXT. In order to evaluate properly my control strategy, I have the need to track the information measured by the color sensor and the data that are being send to the motors. For this, I was trying to implement a simple code to write some similar infos to a .txt file. Here is what I've accomplished so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import lejos.nxt.*;

public class DataLogger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        FileOutputStream fileStream = null;
        try {
            fileStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("Test.txt"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LCD.drawString("Can't make a file", 0, 0);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        DataOutputStream dataStream = new DataOutputStream(fileStream);

        do {
                try {
                    dataStream.writeChars(String.valueOf(count));
                   fileStream.flush();
                    count++;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LCD.drawString("Can't write to the file", 0, 1);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
        } while (count < 100);

        try {
            fileStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LCD.drawString("Can't save the file", 0, 1);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

}
```

With this code I am basically trying to write numbers between 0 and 99 to a file called Test.txt. I don't know why, but the program is writting the data like this:

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 0 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 4 1 5 1 6 1 7 1 8 1 9 2 0 2 1 2
>   2 ...

As you can see, it is adding blank spaces between every digit. I've already tried many writting methods for the DataOutputStream, and `dataStream.writeChars(String.valueOf(count));` was the "most successfull" one (other ones like `writeInt(int b)` write the data according to the ASCII table). I've also tried to use the BufferedOutputStream class, but I had no success. What I could possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by simply substituting `dataStream.writeChars(String.valueOf(count))` by `dataStream.writeBytes(String.valueOf(count))`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method to write basic text data to a file. From the [Java 7 API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) docs:

> FileOutputStream is meant for writing streams of raw bytes such as image data. For writing streams of characters, consider using FileWriter.

Additionally, it's best practice to use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) rather than manually closing the file.

Here's an updated version of your test class which I have tested:

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataLogger {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int count = 0;
        String filename = "Test.txt";
        File file = new File(filename);

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename))) {

            if ( ! file.exists() ) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }

            do {

                writer.write(Integer.toString(count));
                count++;

            } while (count < 100);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that the integer must first be converted to a string, otherwise it will be treated as a character reference.

Also, `System.out.println()` can be used with the EV3 as an alternative to `LCD.drawString()` for ligging errors as it writes on the next available line on the LCD screen (with scrolling) and also saves output to a file on the EV3 for debugging.